# Get Download Url of Image gives downloadable url but not viewable url

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-storage

I upload an Image to Firebase Cloud Storage from the following code:

```
var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
var thisRef = storageRef.child(filename);
thisRef.put(file_from_usr).then((snapshot) => {
    console.log('Uploaded a blob or file!');
});
```

I obtain the Download Url from the following code:

```
var storage = firebase.storage()
ref_to_image = storage.ref(image_name_from_realtime_db);
ref_to_image.getDownloadURL().then((url) => {
    console.log(url)
})
```

The url leads to https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/connectify-21b27.appspot.com/o/ZT.png?alt=media&token=fc791c84-d124-41ba-be1b-ddba04eb1cab where I can download the Image, but I want Url which I can add to src of a  tag

But when I upload an Image manually to the Firebase Cloud Storage, and get the Download Url from the same code, it gives me https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/connectify-21b27.appspot.com/o/sample.jpg?alt=media&token=1722125e-7f12-470c-8e92-4b5ef5334146 which is a viewable url which I could add to the src of a  tag.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the URL that you are currently getting ?

Comment: When you uploaded the file, did you set the metadata with `contentType: 'image/png'`?

Comment: I tried it, but the file then seemed to be corrupted.